# Python unittest - using setupclass, and more than one setup / takedown?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-unittest, class-method

I understand that `setUpClass/tearDownClass` methods are called once for  a class, and `setUp()/tearDown()` are called before/after each unit test. See the code snippet below for this standard setup:

```
class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        do_expensive_setup_of_immutable_objects_used_by_all_tests()

    def setUp(self):
        do_setup_before_each_test()

    def test1(self):
        do_test1_stuff()

    def test2(self):
        do_test1_stuff()

    def tearDown(self):
        do_teardown_after_each_test()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        do_teardown_of_immutable_objects_used_from_all_tests()
```

However, I would like some unit tests to have a different `setUp()` and `tearDown()` from other unit tests. What would be considered a good test structure to achieve this functionality? What options do I have? I am inexperienced in Python and would like to know a good style to adopt for writing unit tests involving expensive `setUp()` procedures.

Comment: Put them in an other class.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, like put what in another class exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what @Klaus means?

```
import unittest


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "Setup # 1"

    def test1(self):
        print "Doing test1"

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "Setup # 2"

    def test2(self):
        print "Doing test2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Alternatively you can change setup based on the method name.
Although this might be a bit more of a pain to maintain.

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        if self._testMethodName == "test1":
            print "Setup # 1"
        elif self._testMethodName == "test2":
            print "Setup # 2"

    def test1(self):
        print "Doing test1"

    def test2(self):
        print "Doing test2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Both produce the same output:

```
Output:
Setup # 1
Doing test1
.Setup # 2
Doing test2
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I don't think I fully understand but here is my attempt at implementing your comment.
My approach here is to reapply `BaseTest.setUp()` rather than try to keep it intact as you described.
`TypeOneTests` and `TypeTwoTests` inherit `BaseTest` and they call `BaseTest`'s `setUp` function inside their own using `super(...)`

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "BaseTest setUp"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "BaseTest tearDown"

    # you could add tests here but I didn't add any based on your comment


class TypeOneTests(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TypeOneTests, self).setUp()
        print "TypeOneTests setUp"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "TypeOneTests tearDown"

    def test(self):
        print "a test in TypeOneTests"


class TypeTwoTests(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TypeTwoTests, self).setUp()
        print "TypeTwoTests additional setUp"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "TypeTwoTests tearDown"
        super(TypeTwoTests, self).tearDown()

    def test(self):
        print "a test in TypeTwoTests"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
BaseTest setUp
TypeOneTests setUp
a test in TypeOneTests
TypeOneTests tearDown
.BaseTest setUp
TypeTwoTests additional setUp
a test in TypeTwoTests
TypeTwoTests tearDown
BaseTest tearDown
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Let me try again to explain. I want to have something more like:
BaseTest setup |
  TypeOneTests setup (building off BaseTest setup) |
     Setup for type one unit test |
     Run unit test |
     Tear down for type one unit test |
   TypeOneTests teardown (leaving BaseTest setup intact) |
   
   TypeTwoTests additional setup |
     Setup for type two unit test |
     Run unit test |
     Tear down for type two unit test |
BaseTest teardown |

How can I achieve this? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @bwrabbit I have edited my post to try and implement your comment.

Comment: thanks very much, your edit accomplishes what I was trying to do! :)